# How to delete a vector background in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, background

I downloaded this image from [Shutterstock](https://www.shutterstock.com/)

[image]

The file is in vector form and I want to get rid of the background using Illustrator. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: You select it, then hit delete. What step are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Direct Selection tool (shortcut A) and then delete. Or the vector is either masked or grouped and you can right-click on the vector and either release or ungroup. If you do that enough you can select the background and then delete.

Answer (score 0):

This is common for imported vector drawings when one wants to edit them: You must break groups, compound paths or clipping masks or all of them.

Select the image, then do

- Object > Ungroup
- Object > Clipping mask > Release
- Object > Compound path > release

I have sometimes repeated these several times until the wanted element was free. After every step check the result. Everything cannot be released without destroying the shapes. Undo, if something weird appears.

Practice beforehand how one troublemaker is dropped out of a bunch of selected objects.